# Page specific event registration design pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have several pages in my application with each page having specific pageid with one common js file.
Im using switch statement in javascript on pageid to register page specific event registrations. I want to know if there is any design pattern to acheieve this solution

Comment: The most important part is that you've realized you've got a problem. There's different ways of handling this (including refactoring your code or restructuring it). What you have doesn't sound "reusable"; it sounds like you've got a literal controller (anti-pattern?) that's inflexible. I would encourage you to look at [Model-View-Controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) and [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), because one, you need to eat your acronyms or you don't get any pudding, and two, but those are common patterns.

Comment: This is traditional application and applying mvc design could be time consuming so could you pls suggest some shorter and easier way of refactoring only javascript file

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, what you have done does not make sense to me. IMHO, you can separate this central code into individual js files specific to your pages. This way every page only has its own js code and no need for switch case.

The code that qualifies to be central/common is usually utils and libs that are non dependent or loosely coupled with their clients. In your case you have tightly coupled a central/common code to something specific, your page ids.